# Make polygon circular in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, qgis-3

I have drawn a polygon in a shape-layer, but it's not perfectly circular. Is there a way to either

1. Draw a circular polygon with a given radius (in a shape-layer)
2. Make a polygon into a circle

I have tried to work around this by creating a point and styling it like my area, but then my point scales with the zoom levels, and it doesn’t look very nice (yes, I am aware of the different styles for different zoom-levels, but that's a lot of work compared to "just" making a circle-polygon instead)

I am using QGIS 3.2.3 with GRASS 7.4.1

Comment: I was just writing the same answer as @ahmadhanb...to add up to that: if you want to keep working with *Points* and their *Labels/Symbology* instead of *Polygons* (which might be useful, depending on what your intentions are), you can set all related units to either `Map untis` or the easier `Meters at Scale` to get zoom depended sizes.

Comment: aha, I didnt know about the scale-options. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `Shape Digitizing` tools which give the option to create circles as you like:

[image]

If it is not shown in QGIS 3, you can enable the toolbar by right-click any where in top menu bars and select `Shape Digitizing tools`:

[image]

Using Add circle by a center point and any other point, I could create a perfect circle:

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do you turn off the shape digitizing once you choose one. I can't make a normal polygon any more.

Comment: Found how to turn off: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/440496/how-to-deselect-shape-digitizing-toolbar-in-qgis

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know, the definition of the shape format doesn't allow circles. So if you save as a shapefile you will end with a polygon.

Comment: If it looks like a circle thats good enough for me, i.e. enough points on a polygon to appear to be a circle

Answer (score 2):

Another way to create circles is using the Buffer processing tool.

1. You should be in a Project CRS that has its units in meters eg: 3857.
2. Create a new Shapefile layer. Add a point where you like the center of the circle to be.
3. In the processing tools search bar type in Buffer
4. Select the point layer that you just created
5. Add the appropriate distance. This will be the diameter of your circle.
6. Click Run.
7. A new layer will be generated as the circle.