# How to deselect Shape Digitizing Toolbar in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, digitizing, toolbar

I'm using QGIS 3.26 for Windows.
Usually, after I create new shapefile layer, I can freely draw polygon by freehand.
Suddenly the shape digitizing toolbar Rectangle option is selected and I cannot deselect it.

How to deselect this feature?

Answer (score 3):

This caught me out at first too.

Ensure the *Advanced digitizing* toolbar is visible (`View > Toolbars > Advanced Digitizing Toolbar`), then select *Digitize with Segment* in the dropdown.

[image]

Comment: When I follow your directions, using 3.26.3, the *only* shape that can be digitized is a circle.  How to digitize a rectangle?

Comment: @StuSmith, do you also have the `Shape Digitizing Toolbar` activated?

Comment: Yes, the Shape Digitizing Toolbar is activated.  But for some reason, at both 3.22 and 3.26, the *Digitize with Segment* option does not appear in the dropdown, leaving me without that capability.  I upgraded to 3.28, and *Digitize with Segment* now appears.  With your help the problem is solved!